# java.util.zip.ZipException when adding a ZipEntry to a ZipOutputStream without a ZipInputStream

Tags: java, byte, zipoutputstream

I am attempting to add a `ZipEntry` to a `ZipOutputStream` but am running into problems when trying to write the bytes.

I got the `ZipEntry` from a `HashMap` which maps file names to their `ZipEntries`. I chose this method because I am dealing with a large `ZipInputStream` and I want be able to access its contents easier than looping through the `InputStream` and looking for a file and getting its `ZipEntry`.

This causes a problem when I try to write the bytes after I added the entry. All the solutions I have found so far have needed the `ZipInputStream`.

Here is the code:

```
ZipEntry ze = entryHash.get(pathToString(path));
zos.putNextEntry(ze);
zos.write(new byte[(int)ze.getSize()]); // Problem Here
zos.closeEntry();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 389 but got 12 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:248)
```

How can I fix this exception?

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: you need to write your file at this point ...

Comment: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 389 but got 12 bytes) is my error. What do you mean write the file? You mean close the ZipOutputStream? I want to add more before I do that. Thanks for the extremely fast replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *new* ZipEntry to add to the ZipOutputStream. But your code doesn't make any sense. You're not copying the old ZipEntry to the output with this technique, you're just writing an array of zero bytes of the same size. You have to read from the old ZipEntry and write to the new output. Your technique of a map of ZipEntries isn't going to work either. A Zip file must be processed sequentially.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I had a feeling I was missing a large concept.